# Capital Recovery Factor for Hyperbolic Discounting

Tags: reference-request, behavioral-economics

I'm looking for a closed-form capital recovery factor when hyperbolic discounting is used. The Wikipedia article on hyperbolic discounting has this formula for the "present value of a series of equal annual cash flows in arrears discounted hyperbolically":
$$
V = P \frac{\ln(1 + kd)}{k}\ ,
$$
but does not include any references.

If I attempt to sum the series $\sum_{t=1}^n 1/(1 + rt)$ however, WolframAlpha gives me a more complicated formula involving the digamma function.

I would appreciate a reference for this CRF, if one exists. A derivation would be a bonus. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like they've just approximated the sum with an integral

Comment: The sum will not have an exact form. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number. This pages gives some nice asymptotic expansions in the case $r=1$. The logarithm approximation is pretty good though.

Comment: @B.Martin, thank you, that's helpful. Do you have a reference for the log approximation?

Comment: I don't have any specific references, but replacing a sum with an integral is a relatively common approximation. And in this case, you will end up with a really good approximation for large $n$. It will basically just be off by a small constant. Also to be completely transparent, I'm not that familiar with the economics of this situation, and was just giving the equations a look at.

Comment: @B.Martin, ah of course, that makes sense with the intergral. Thanks for the help! If you want to summarise this is in an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just expand upon what I've said in the comments as an answer. The sum $$\sum_{t=0}^n \frac{1}{1+rt}$$ will not have a nice closed form. However what wikipedia has done is approximate this sum as an integral. The integral will just be $$\int_{t=0}^n \frac{dt}{1+rt}=\frac1r\ln(1+rt)|_0^n=\frac1r \ln(1+nr)$$ Which is basically what you've got without multiplying by the principle value, and relabelling some variables. Now something to watch out for is that this will be off by a small constant. If you look at the diagram below, there is some error area that the integral fails to pick up, so it will actually be slightly smaller. 
 [image]
In this case however you know the error area is below 1 (because if you imagine sliding each error area into the first square (purely horizontally it will not fill it all up)

[image] and above one half, (draw a line between the corners of each error area to make a triangle and each triangle is half the area of the corresponding rectangle, so the sum of all the triangles is half the area of the unit square)[image]

So since the error is between 1 and a half, for large n it should be pretty insignificant, and this is a pretty good approximation.